# Как узнать subprocess который не закрыт в [nodemon] при перезагрузке сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Я пишу Node.js сервер c express и nodemon.

на сервере я использую childProcces spawn

```
object['staticProperty']['process'] = spawn('./dir',
        ['-C'],
        {
            shell: true,
            detached: true,
        });
```

Убить процесс я могу и тогда проблем нет.
Но nodemon перезагрузает сервер когда происходят изменения.

Когда сервер перезагружается
У spawn запускаются

```
 object['staticProperty']['process'].on('exit', (code) => {})
```

и

```
 object['staticProperty']['process'].on('close', (code) => {})
```

Это на сколько я понимаю говорит о том, что процесс завершён.

Но в nodemon начинается бесконечный цикл...

```
[nodemon] still waiting for 1 subprocess(es) to finish...
[nodemon] still waiting for 1 subprocess(es) to finish...
[nodemon] still waiting for 1 subprocess(es) to finish...
[nodemon] still waiting for 1 subprocess(es) to finish...
[nodemon] still waiting for 1 subprocess(es) to finish...
```

Как мне понять, что это за процесс и как его убрать ?

Comment: известная тема, смотрите тут https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1025, может какое решение вам поможет

Comment: Спасибо. Я решил её уже.